# How to see YouTube video title in landscape mode?

Tags: youtube

Scenario: Playing a mix playlist in car dock in landscape mode. Like current song and want to see name.

How do I do this?

Things I've tried:

- Collapsing the video just shows the mini player in the corner with playlist in background, no video info.
- Onscreen menus have no choices that show video info.
- Tapping while playing also shows no video info.

Workarounds, sort of:

- I can turn the device to portrait and info shows. Not convenient when in dock or while driving.
- I can share the video with myself via email then scroll down and read the email body without sending it. Also inconvenient and stops the song since YouTube can't play in background. (And, philosophically, this is a goofy way to do this.)

How can I see the name of the video (song in my case) currently playing? I'm sure there is a simple way that I am just missing.

Android 4.4.2, and whatever the latest version of YouTube is at the time of this writing, with the new fancy red top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since YouTube v11.13.56 (April 14, 2016), tapping the screen while in landscape mode will show the video title (alongside other info).

[image]

<sup>The video title can now be seen in landscape mode</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you have another device with you, you can use Google Now's voice command to ask what song is playing. Be sure to enable the "always listening" option in the Google app's settings.

This might work on the same phone, but I believe when you launch the voice command, it will pause the YouTube video.

Comment: It does stop video on the same phone. If I had a second device I'd just tape it to my dashboard in portrait mode and play music on it instead, hehe. :)

Comment: Ah. When you get a new phone, you return your old one or keep it? Maybe you can use that once you do get a new one.

Comment: Maybe... But surely there must be a way to see the title of the video...

Comment: One good solution would be to purchase Play Music All Access, and you can play the video in the background. Your screen would turn off, but you can turn it on and they music is displayed on your lock screen.